# How to avoid redirect loops in apache vhost

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, virtualhost

I have tried the following setup and get loops:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin my@example.org
ServerName www.example.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/../../../
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin my@example.org
ServerName example.org
RedirectPermanent / http://www.example.org/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin my@example.org
ServerName www.example.org
RedirectPermanent / http://www.example.org/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin my@example.org
ServerName example.org
RedirectPermanent / http://www.example.org/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I do it the other way around i.e. redirecting 80 to 443 this setup works.

What I basically want to achieve is that when I go to

- `https://www.example.org`
- `https://example.org`
- `http://example.org`

server redirects to `http://www.example.org`

There must be a trick. Thanks and cheers

Comment: I do not want to use ServerAlias since people either end up at example.org or www.example.org.

Comment: To clarify. Is this what you want? If you put https://www.example.og -> redirects you to https://example.org and finally redirects you to http://example.og. Is that right. With your current setup, what are you obtaining?

Comment: No, everything should redirect to http://www.example.org 1 is the document root at http://www.example.org, 2 should redricect to http://www.example.org, 3 should redirect to http://www.example.org and 4 should redirect to http://www.example.org. This is why the redirects are all http

Comment: So with this setup, when you try https://example.org, what response do you obtain from server?

Comment: The browser does the looping. :(

Comment: But can you show the looping? If you are using Firefox or Chrome, you should be able to use the web developer tools to follow the results, or if you are running on linux (or have some cygwin you can use curl).

Comment: Ah, yeah, I get a 301 moved permanently. Hmm ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23660/discussion-between-alphamikevictor-and-kghbln).

Comment: I'd love to but I will have to attend a meeting in about 5 minutes. But basically what you are saying is that the setup looks allright?

Comment: Not really, just to have more elements to try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I just tested with other browsers, e.g. with Chrome and Opera. They do not have these loops. So I guess Firefox is messing up. Strange. Will investigate later.

Comment: Indeed a Firefox only issue. :(

Comment: Yes, we are wasting our time here. This issue  appears only with FF on Linux Mint. Ubuntu is ok. Win8 is ok. Chrome and Opera on all platforms are ok. Thanks for trying to help.